# Is it possible to import third-party data into D365 F&O using an API with real-time updates?

Tags: azure-web-app-service, microsoft-dynamics, finance

I have a client which is using my portal for processing payroll. They wanted to import all payroll related data into their D365 F&O.

I went through a few documentation but I can find only file based import/export. We want to do this API based and real time.

I'm ready to create an API which contains the data. But how will I import this to D365 F&O? or Is there an MS API which I can send my data into?

Below are few documentation I went through:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/fin-ops-core/dev-itpro/data-entities/integration-overview

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/fin-ops-core/dev-itpro/data-entities/data-management-api

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/fin-ops-core/dev-itpro/data-entities/odata

Comment: Did you happen to look at the Recurring API integration here- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/fin-ops-core/dev-itpro/data-entities/recurring-integrations and also this Forum post on the same ask- https://community.dynamics.com/365/financeandoperations/f/dynamics-365-for-finance-and-operations-forum/310648/sending-data-from-third-party-to-import-into-d365fo Also refer the answers here-https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/microsoft-dynamics-crm-forum/270302/how-to-call-3rd-party-api-from-dynamics-365-online